# How to update one table from another table having more than 1 row with matching conditions? - in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have table A with product_id,cost,year,quarter,... etc columns.
I have another table B with product_id,base_cost,current_year,p_year,p_quarter,p_order columns.

I want to write an update query to update A from B. My conditions are -

```
WHERE A.product_id=B.product_id
and A.year=B.current_year
and A.year=B.p_year and A.quarter>B.p_quarter
and A.cost=0;
```

But the problem is, with these conditions if i have more than one rows in B then i only want to update from the row of B which has the minimum of all quarters.

Example 1-

If A has one row as:

```
product_id  cost   year  quarter
102         0      2019  1
102         0      2019  2
102         0      2019  3
102         0      2019  4
```

And B has two rows corresponding to the where clause:

```
product_id  cost  current_year p_year  quarter
102         3.5   2019         2019     3      
102         1.8   2019         2019     1      
102         0.5   2019         2019     2
```

Then updated A should be:

```
product_id  cost   year  quarter
102         0      2019  1
102         1.8    2019  2
102         1.8    2019  3
102         1.8    2019  4
```

Comment: So you want to pick the row with the smallest value for `quarter` in table `b` to update table `a`?

Comment: Yes, with this condition- that row of B should have product_id,current_year same as product_id,year in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem which you need to apply to the table `b` in a sub-select:

```
UPDATE A
  SET cost = B.base_cost
FROM (
  select distinct on (product_id, current_year) product_id, current_year, cost
  from b
  order by product_id, current_year, quarter
) b  
WHERE A.product_id = B.product_id
  AND A.year = B.current_year
  AND A.cost = 0
```

Comment: Can you answer my other question?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61253120/how-to-update-one-table-from-another-table-based-on-some-priority-that-depends-o